# PowerApp Image to text using

Tags: powerapps

I have followed all the steps in the https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qXSRKfYqYMM where the app is taking a picture of text and converting it to text using the computer vision flow.

I have tried many times following the steps but I am constantly getting an error "Invalid number of arguments: received 1, expected 2" with my flow button any ideas what is wrong

`Camera OnSelect:  ClearCollect(colPhoto, Camera2.Photo)`

`Image: Collect(colImageDesc, ComputerVisionAPI.DescribeImageContentV2(First(colPhoto).Url).description)`

`Gallery: First(colImageDesc).tags`

Comment: Please post your codes here.

Answer (score 0):

PowerApps has really good IntelliSense built into the formula bar. Type in the first part of the Flow Syntax: ‘ComputerVisionAPI.DescribeImageContentV2(‘ and look just above the formula bar. In bold, you will see what the first required parameter is. Add a comma and you’ll see the next required parameter and so on. 
When you see “...” in the IntelliSense, this means the next parameter is optional. 
In your case, it’s probably something like API version, etc.